# Polyurethane Gummy After Cure

Tags: polyurethane, wood-finish

I finished a plywood table top with varathane water-based polyurethane over a year ago.  The top was hard and used extensively after curing.

Recently my daughter was playing with modeling clay (that you bake to harden) on that table top.  The clay was left sitting on the table for about a week.  When I cleaned up I found that the polyurethane became gummy in the spots in contact with the clay.  When I wipe gummy spots I'm now back to the wood.  The rest of the table not in contact with the clay is fine.

If anyone has an idea what reaction is going on I would be grateful.  Or if anyone can suggest a different topcoat not at risk to whatever reaction I'm experiencing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Imagine it was the moisture in the clay plus leaving it for week that did it.  A finish that gives waterproofing or just a piece of plexiglass as a cover when using clay should help.

Comment: So use a work mat to protect any surface.